# Cycle detection that handles a series of directed edges?

Tags: algorithm

Is there an algorithm faster than topological sort or DFSto handle time series of edges?

(1) at time t = 0, there is one node.

(2) at each time t > 0, an edge comes along. At least one of the edge's endpoints was added into the graph before t.

I want to detect at each time t if there is a *directed cycle*.

I really want to take advantage of the input being a time series. But the algorithms I know all deal with static graph.

A good reference that is unlikely to be a broken link: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Comment: Do you know in advance the total number of nodes in the graph, or is always dynamically growing?

Comment: @jdehesa it's dynamically growing, so the total number of nodes is unkown.

Comment: @juvian Yes it's duplicate. Thx! Feel free to close.

Comment: @Leedehai: Closing works best if you do it yourself.